# svn-update version mismatch with commit version

Tags: linux, svn

I'm having this issue updating my code with my partner's code. My partner's last submission was on revision 36, but when I updated my working directory svn said the version jumped to 38. I don't know why it did this. When I was updating I made one of the conflicting files accept my version. Also my partner copied something into her own svn before I updated mine. Which part of these caused the mismatch in the version number? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the SVN log to see what revisions 37 and 38 were?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth   well the thing is, when I checked svn log, it says the revision only came up to r36. I don't know where r37 and 38 went

Comment: You're saying that if you do `svn info SomeFile`, it says 38, but if you do `svn log SomeFile`, it only goes up to 36?  That is extremely suspicious.

Comment: @user1926344 - if you log not from root of repo, you may have skipped revisons, if they are outside "command root"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revison in Subversion is global attribute of repository, each subtree can and may own revision less than HEAD-revision of repo

Check with `svn info` state of your working copy. As example for trunk of one of my repo

```
...
Revision: 37
...
Last Changed Rev: 36
```

i.e - latest revision **in repo** is 37, but in trunk subtree - only 36